# rails create a collection select from a array of db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

how i create a collection select with array of numbers from a integer db field or any other kind?

exemple:

**Item from db**

```
<Item id: 167, name: "x", quantity: 6, 
created_at: "2012-04-27 18:49:07", updated_at: "2012-04-27 18:49:07" >
```

**Item show**

```
<%= select("item", "quantity", 1..10) %>
```

i would like just to show the quantity from the db

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select("item", "quantity", Item.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]})
```

**EDIT**

what about this:

```
  select("item", "quantity", Item.all.collect.(&:id))
```

Comment: thank's Mohit, this method gets the number 6 but not the array of the field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good number of methods dealing with select tags and options in the [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) : `collection_select`, `grouped_collection_select`... typing 'collection_sel' in the search field should show you a good number of them. Seems to me the one you want is `collection_select`.

Comment: collection_select seems to be the right method for this, fits to the the array?

Comment: I don't use it often enough to remember how to use it correctly and where the args goes - that's what the doc is here for

Comment: in this specific case don't have on docs, so that's why i'm here!